# Laravel file upload NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel to upload an image to my folder.

```
$file = Input::file('largeImage');
$filePath = '/uploads/'.date("Y/m").'/'.time().'/';
$path = $filePath;
$file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

The image is successfully uploaded.

Now when I try to access it:

```
http://localhost:8080/uploads/2015/01/1420644761/10377625_673554946025652_6686347512849117388_n.jpg
```

I'm having the `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` error.

I even tried `http://localhost:8080/public/uploads/2015/01/1420644761/10377625_673554946025652_6686347512849117388_n.jpg`

But the same error. What might be the problem? I checked the uploads folder and the image is there.

Comment: From the error it looks like a `Route::`ing issue, but it's odd that you'd need to define a route for a file like this, so I'm not sure. Let me look more into this.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a call to public_path helper:

```
$filePath = public_path() . '/uploads/'.date("Y/m").'/'.time().'/';
```

Otherwise it will place it in the app root, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    $file = Input::file('largeImage');
    $filePath = '/uploads/'.date("Y/m").'/'.time().'/';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path().$filePath;
    $file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Tom's answer is correct for this situation, but defining a `Route` can be used to download any file from the system, which is good to know too. Glad you got this working though!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it IS a Routing Issue. To solve this particular one, define a `Route::get` that navigates to your file.

```
Route::get("/download/{year}/{month}/{time}/{filename}", "Controller@downloadFile");
```

Then you'll need a function in that controller that handles the file download:

```
public function downloadFile($year, $month, $time, $filename){
  $path = public_path()."/uploads/".$year."/".$month."/".$time."/".$filename".jpg";
  // Should equate to: "/uploads/2015/01/142064476110377625_673554946025652_6686347512849117388_n.jpg
  return Response::download($path, 'image.jpg');
}
```

Which in theory should work for your needs. The path may need to be modified to fit your needs but this should be the general idea. Test that out and let me know if it works.

**Note**

This isn't the best way to handle downloads, as you need to know the exact filename of the file you want, but it points you in the right direction.

Comment: This will only work if he first moved the file to the upload folder in the public web directory of Laravel. That is what he isn't doing.

Comment: Yeah, so he'd have to use your answer first. I did write in there "The path may need to be modified to fit your needs, but ..." so I did address that.

Comment: Actually it should work if he removes `public_path()` (or adds it at the upload) However if it's in the public directory a download route isn't needed (unless you want a force download)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. So depending on where you actually save the file determines how you can access it to download. Good to know.

Comment: Yep. For everything in public you can just link to the actual file. Other files need to be accessed via route that reads the file

Comment: Awesome. That's actually quite helpful to know, thanks!